# Changing App name from .env file

Tags: ios, fastlane

I am trying to build multiple apps from same codebase using targets. I am using Fastlane, `.env` files to launch different builds. Build is uploading fine with different app_identifiers but I am not able to change app name through `.env` files

Following is my sample `.env.target1` file:

```
SCHEME_NAME=SampleFastlaneTesting
BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER=com.*****.SampleFastlaneTesting
APP_NAME=“SampleFastlaneTesting”
```

I am storing app name of each build using "APP_NAME" key. In deliver file 
I am setting as follows:

```
name ENV[‘APP_NAME’]
```

According to this [link](https://docs.fastlane.tools/faqs/#multiple-targets-of-the-same-underlying-app) it should work but it is not updating when I launch the build. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you said the filename you are using is `.env.target1`. You can find how fastlane uses `.env` files [here](https://docs.fastlane.tools/best-practices/keys/#dotenv), so if you want to use that file you need to call fastlane with `fastlane --env target1 <your lane>`.

To actually update the name of your app that is shown on the home screen, you need to use the `update_info_plist` action. Edit your lane and include the following before running `gym` (or just place it at the beginning):

```
update_info_plist(
  plist_path: "path/to/Info.plist", # !!! Set to your Info.plist's path !!!
  display_name: ENV["APP_NAME"],
  app_identifier: ENV["BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER"]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changed "APP_NAME" with "BUNDLE_DISPLAY_NAME" or "DISPLAY_NAME"

Edit:

Reading fastlane, this [update_info_plist](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/update_info_plist/#update_info_plist) could help you.

Comment: No it did not work. Morover my key in .env file is "APP_NAME". For bundle identifier this was working but for name it is not

Comment: I tried your solution but it did not work. I tried adding update_info_plist in deliver file but it gave following error

Could not find option 'update_info_plist' in the list of available options: username, app_identifier, app, edit_live, ipa, pkg, platform, metadata_path, screenshots_path ......
Anyway thank you for response

Comment: My main problem is how can i change meta data specifically name, description, keywords etc using .env files during building

Answer (score 0):

**main problem is how can i change meta data specifically name, description, keywords etc using .env files**

I think it'd work if you set `ENV[‘APP_NAME’]` in name.txt (when you download metadata) and so forth for other metadata.

One more thing to try on is this on your DeliverFile (**I tested this and works if you don't have the metadata text file when you download metadata**):

```
name({
  'default' => ENV[‘APP_NAME’],
  'en-US' => ENV['APP_NAME']
})
```

Run env:

```
fastlane yourLane --env target1
```

*Example Lane:*

```
  desc "Upload metadata only"
  lane :upload_metadata do
     sh "fastlane deliver skip_screenshots --app_identifier # {ENV['APP_IDENTIFIER']}"
  end
```

*Example ENV run with example lane:*

```
fastlane upload_metadata --env target1
```